# Sort LinkedHashMap<String, Json> by value without losing keys

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, linkedhashmap

I have this retrofit response body as LinkedHashMap< String, Json>

```
"-M74DWOrW0w07BpfmBVo": {
  "noteContent": "Note 1 content",
  "noteCurrentTime": 1589225588206,
  "noteTitle": "Note 1"
},
"-M74Dc2dDAZgVk6q86Rs": {
  "noteContent": "Note 2 content",
  "noteCurrentTime": 1589225990674,
  "noteTitle": "Note 2"
},
"-M74DmbSNQnjEU0Hw4yQ": {
  "noteContent": "Note 3 content",
  "noteCurrentTime": 1589225658614,
  "noteTitle": "Note 3"
}
}
```

I need to sort by 'noteCurrentTime' value. So far, this is how get the array of sorted values.

```
private fun sortJsonArray(valuesArray: JSONArray): JSONArray? {
        val sortedValues: MutableList<JSONObject> = ArrayList()
        for (i in 0 until valuesArray.length()) {
            sortedValues.add(valuesArray.getJSONObject(i))
        }
        sortedValues.sortWith(Comparator { lhs, rhs ->
            val lid: Long = lhs.getLong("noteCurrentTime")
            val rid: Long = rhs.getLong("noteCurrentTime")
            lid.compareTo(rid)
        })

        return JSONArray(sortedValues)
    }
```

However, this only returns sorted values, without keys, which are now in a wrong order. Is there a way to sort values of LinkedHashMap and keep the correct order of keys? Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the map to a list (of key-value pairs), sort that, and then convert it back.

I don't really know what type is `Json` in your example Map value type. But you would convert it in the `sortedBy` lambda however is necessary to get your Long date.

```
val response:  LinkedHashMap<String, Json> = //...
val sorted: Map<String, Json> = response.toList().sortBy { (_, jsonValue) ->
    jsonValue.getLong("noteCurrentTime")
}.toMap()
```